# White image on white background can't be seen in table cell

Tags: css

On this [page](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/other-links/) I have some links. One in particular is for Cascade Design:

[image: Cascade]

```
<tr>
    <td style="border-bottom-color:#eeeeee;border-top-color:#eeeeee;border-width:1px;text-align:center"
        data-border-color="#eeeeee">
        <img class="wp-image-1564" 
             style="width: px;" 
             src="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cascade-logo-white.png" 
             alt="" 
             srcset="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cascade-logo-white.png 369w, https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cascade-logo-white-300x85.png 300w"
             sizes="(max-width: 369px) 100vw, 369px">
    </td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color:#eeeeee;border-top-color:#eeeeee;border-width:1px"
        data-border-color="#eeeeee">
           <a rel="noreferrer noopener" 
              href="http://www.cascadedesign.co.uk/" 
              target="_blank">Cascade Design</a>&nbsp;offers services for Design | Web | Branding | Media. 
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that by design the logo for this company is white and my website background is white. What is the best way to present the image with CSS styling in this cell so it can be seen?

Comment: [either set background to a different colour or add `box-shadow:0 0 2px #222`](https://jsfiddle.net/6eqfpLdv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I set the background-color to `#eaeaea` where it make the image visible. You can change it to any color you like.

```html
<tr>
    <td style="border-bottom-color:#eeeeee;border-top-color:#eeeeee;border-width:1px;text-align:center"
        data-border-color="#eeeeee">
        <img class="wp-image-1564" 
             style="background-color: #eaeaea" 
             src="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cascade-logo-white.png" 
             alt="" 
             srcset="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cascade-logo-white.png 369w, https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cascade-logo-white-300x85.png 300w"
             sizes="(max-width: 369px) 100vw, 369px">
    </td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color:#eeeeee;border-top-color:#eeeeee;border-width:1px"
        data-border-color="#eeeeee">
           <a rel="noreferrer noopener" 
              href="http://www.cascadedesign.co.uk/" 
              target="_blank">Cascade Design</a>&nbsp;offers services for Design | Web | Branding | Media. 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I coud not work out how to apply a background to the image but I was able to do it to the specific cell. I think it is fine. Thank you!